# jQuery fadein without a set height

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery based fadein and fadeout routine which is working great..

```
<ul>
    <li class="tab"><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content1">Link 1</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content2">Link 2</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content3">Link 3</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content4">Link 4</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content5">Link 5</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="content-container">
    <div id="content1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla venenatis eros tincidunt sem feugiat eleifend. Ut commodo lectus eu ultricies semper. Mauris pellentesque malesuada urna quis interdum. Nam urna lacus, tempus id dictum non, imperdiet vel nibh. Aliquam ornare auctor lorem, non blandit velit fringilla quis. Ut eget arcu at eros interdum tincidunt sed sed velit. Donec feugiat lectus magna, eget tincidunt erat tempus nec. Nam eget est diam. Quisque commodo facilisis odio eget sodales. Fusce sollicitudin dui magna, a mattis sem ornare id. Maecenas hendrerit fermentum nibh scelerisque varius.</div>
    <div id="content2">This is the test content for part 2</div>
    <div id="content3">This is the test content for part 3</div>
    <div id="content4">This is the test content for part 4</div>
    <div id="content5">This is the test content for part 5</div>
</div>


Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus. 

 jQuery( function() {
    jQuery(".link").click(function() {
      if( jQuery( this ).hasClass( 'active' ) ) {
         return;
      }

      jQuery('.active').removeClass('active');
      jQuery( this.parentNode ).addClass( 'active' );

      jQuery('.content-container div').fadeOut('slow');
      jQuery('#' + jQuery(this).data('rel')).fadeIn('slow');
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/my5pqas5/

My issue is that the div content that is faded in overlaps the existing content.  I know I can resolve this my by setting a height for the div, but my content is dyanmically generated and so is different height.

How can I resolve?  Auto height in CSS doesn't have any effect

Comment: Why don't you just delete position:absolute; in '.content-container div {'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use relative positioning instead of absolute

fully working fiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/3vhLsnx1/

```js
    jQuery( function() {
    jQuery(".link").click(function() {
      if( jQuery( this.parentNode ).hasClass( 'active' ) ) {
         return;
      }

      jQuery('.active').removeClass('active');
      jQuery( this.parentNode  ).addClass( 'active' );
       var container= this;
        jQuery('.content-container div').fadeOut('slow').promise().done(function(){showData(container)});
     
  });
     function showData(container){
     jQuery('#' + jQuery(container).data('rel')).fadeIn('slow');}
});
```

```css
.content-container {
    position: relative;
}
.content-container div {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="tab"><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content1">Link 1</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content2">Link 2</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content3">Link 3</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content4">Link 4</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content5">Link 5</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="content-container">
    <div id="content1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla venenatis eros tincidunt sem feugiat eleifend. Ut commodo lectus eu ultricies semper. Mauris pellentesque malesuada urna quis interdum. Nam urna lacus, tempus id dictum non, imperdiet vel nibh. Aliquam ornare auctor lorem, non blandit velit fringilla quis. Ut eget arcu at eros interdum tincidunt sed sed velit. Donec feugiat lectus magna, eget tincidunt erat tempus nec. Nam eget est diam. Quisque commodo facilisis odio eget sodales. Fusce sollicitudin dui magna, a mattis sem ornare id. Maecenas hendrerit fermentum nibh scelerisque varius.</div>
    <div id="content2">This is the test content for part 2</div>
    <div id="content3">This is the test content for part 3</div>
    <div id="content4">This is the test content for part 4</div>
    <div id="content5">This is the test content for part 5</div>
</div>


Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus.
```

Comment: This works great but the .active class isn't being applied to the tab anymore.  any ideas why?

Comment: @fightstarr20 edited to work on tab .active

earlier you did something like this if( jQuery( this ).hasClass('active' ) ) { return; } whitch wasnt wqorking at all, so i asumed that you wanted to give <a element active class so i removed parentNode from this line jQuery( this.parentNode ).addClass( 'active' );

Answer (score 1):

Give `position:relative` to `.content-container div`

or simply you can remove `position` from `.content-container div` since position relative is already given for `.content-container` in your code.

working fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Ashish_developer/y7s2bu3r/

Comment: But then that introduces a bit of jumping when you go for example, from 1 to 3.  Anyway to remove that?

Comment: @fightstarr20   try fiddle in my post, i managed to avoid jumping.